# Is it possible to make a function always run in the same thread? [C++]

Tags: c++, multithreading

Simple Example you have two functions, foo and baz. Baz calls foo. Even baz is launched from a separate thread can you run the foo it calls in the main thread?

```
int foo(int Z)
{
    cout << Z;
    return 0;
}

int baz(int Z)
{
   return foo(-Z);
}


int main()
{
   
   foo(6); // foo is run in main thread
   baz(6); // baz is run in main thread
  thread th2(baz,7); // baz is run in thread 2, but its call to foo is run in the main thread

}
```

Comment: you'll have to listen to some kind of messages in the main thread to run requests from another thread

Comment: std::condition_variable

Comment: Does it have to be in the main thread? You could synchronize all calls to `foo` with a mutex no matter which thread calls it.

Comment: C++20 can make such things fairly easy with coroutines. However, you'll probably need a 3rd party library that provides the synchronization primitives since the standard doesn't provide any for us yet. With that, you could even switch between threads in the middle of the function.

Comment: SImple answer: No. Anyhow, I think you're asking the wrong question and that this is a so-called "XY problem".

Comment: @super It doesn't have to be in the main thread. I just thought that would be the simplest to get an example working. How would synchronization help here? Wouldn't that still execute foo in it's own thread even if it runs one at a time?

Comment: @phuclv Can you elaborate on this or direct me to an example?

Comment: @knowads Yes, that would only stop multiple threads from running the function simultaneously. If that's not enough for you it would be good to try and clarify your use case. If you need 1 and only 1 specific thread to run the function you need some way to communicate with that thread. Tell it when to run and retrieve any possible return values. `std::condition_variable` being the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: @super My real usecase is more similar to this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295447/how-do-i-specify-which-core-a-pthread-is-spawned-on where I want foo to actually be assigned a dedicated core without making my entire program utilize only one core. I just wanted to see if it was possible to separate the program cleanly in software first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` can be a wrapper around the actual implementation `fooImpl`. `foo` would figure out if it can call `fooImpl` directly, or if it has to use some synchronization mechanism to provide all the input parameters to a forever running thread, and trigger that thread to execute the `fooImpl`, and then retrieve the output (if there are any).

Comment: Hi @Dialectius, this is really good. If you can direct me to a very simple example or show how the above example can be changed to accomodate this I can accept this answer.

Comment: @knowads sorry, can't do that. It would take me an hour to write it and test it.